# vb.net : Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table

Tags: vb.net

i have follow code in my vb.net project
the connection to the sql db is fine & ok , only when i try to fill the listbox i get a error

```
Public Class Form1
    Private myTable As New DataTable()

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    GetSerialPortNames()
    FillListBox()

    '------------
    myTable.Columns.Add("naam", GetType(String))
    myTable.Columns.Add("waarde", GetType(Integer))   '<<<< change the type of this column to what you actually need instead of integer.


    ListBox1.DisplayMember = "naam"
    ListBox1.ValueMember = "waarde"
    ListBox1.DataSource = myTable

End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub FillListBox()
    Dim naam As String
    Dim stringConn As String
    Dim stringCmd As String
    Dim myConn As MySqlConnection
    Dim myCmd As MySqlCommand

    'Frame your query here.
    stringCmd = "SELECT id,naam,voornaam FROM deelnemers WHERE finger = FALSE ORDER BY naam "

    'Frame your connection string here.
    stringConn = "********************************************"

    'Get your connection here.
    myConn = New MySqlConnection(stringConn)

    'Get a command by using your connection and query.
    myCmd = New MySqlCommand(stringCmd, myConn)

    'Open the connection.
    myConn.Open()

    'create a reader to store the datum which will be returned from the DB
    Dim myReader As MySqlDataReader

    'Execute your query using .ExecuteReader()
    myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader()

    'Reset your List box here.
    ListBox2.Items.Clear()

    While (myReader.Read())
        'Add the items from db one by one into the list box.
        naam = myReader.GetString(1) & " " & myReader.GetString(2)
        'ListBox2.Items.Add((naam))
        myTable.Rows.Add(naam, myReader.GetString(0))
    End While

    'Close the reader and the connection.
    myReader.Close()
    myConn.Close()

End Sub
```

i get error on follow line

```
myTable.Rows.Add(naam, myReader.GetString(0))
```

with follow description : Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.

someone who see ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your `myTable` datatable does not have any columns...

Try changing:

```
While (myReader.Read())
    'Add the items from db one by one into the list box.
    naam = myReader.GetString(1) & " " & myReader.GetString(2)
    'ListBox2.Items.Add((naam))
    myTable.Rows.Add(naam, myReader.GetString(0))
End While
```

to this:

```
Dim row As DataRow
While (myReader.Read())
    'Add the items from db one by one into the list box.
    row = myTable.NewRow()
    row("naam") = myReader.GetString(1) & " " & myReader.GetString(2)
    row("waarde") = myReader.GetString(0)
    myTable.Rows.Add(row)
End While
```

you should still get an error, but at least this way you'll know what columns are missing...

**update**

Also, change this:

```
FillListBox()

'------------
myTable.Columns.Add("naam", GetType(String))
myTable.Columns.Add("waarde", GetType(Integer))   '<<<< change the type of this column to what you actually need instead of integer.
```

to this:

```
'------------
myTable.Columns.Add("naam", GetType(String))
myTable.Columns.Add("waarde", GetType(Integer))   '<<<< change the type of this column to what you actually need instead of integer.

FillListBox()
```

Comment: get error : De kolom naam hoort niet bij de tabel . So its colum naam

Comment: sorry, I don't speak dutch... :) But yeah, that just confirms that the datatable has missing columns...

Comment: but i create them   myTable.Columns.Add("naam", GetType(String))
    myTable.Columns.Add("waarde", GetType(Integer))

Comment: check out my update... you add the columns only after invoking the `FillListBox()` function..